# How "Our Choice" app does the pinch and enlarge to view content part?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, pinch

The said app can be seen here: http://pushpoppress.com/ourchoice/. What interests me is the part where they can freely pinch the thumbnails at the bottom to enlarge to full view. Would be interesting to replicate such effect.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2):

### To rotate the image:

import math.h

in touchesbegan: find firsttouch, secondtouch, etc.

then:
float startdirection = tanh((firsttouch.y-secondtouch.y)/(firsttouch.x-secondtouch.x));

in touchesmoved:
find firsttouch, secondtouch again, then:

float newdirection = tanh((firsttouch.y-secondtouch.y)/(firsttouch.x-secondtouch.x));

image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newdirection-startdirection);

Comment: Nice. I haven't tried the code yet. But this should work for pinching and zooming the thumbnail. Next to figure out how they make the smooth transition from thumbnail to full view once fully zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use touchesBegan but enumerate the touches and use the distance between the points, their positions, etc. to manipulate the size and position of a UIImageView. Then if the distance is large enough it could automatically jump to full screen.

Comment: Your description of how to execute the interaction is correct. However, I am looking for some code to duplicate such interaction. One interesting thing about "Our Choice" is that not only it scales according to the pinch, but also rotates with the fingers. (which is the part I am confused about)

Comment: If I were to do this I would use trig to figure out the direction and use CGAffine add transformation to rotate it. (see the newest answer)